# Странное поведение метода контроллера

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Доброго времени суток. Осваиваю потихоньку Spring и столкнулся с странностью при работе метода контроллера:

```
@ModelAttribute("status")    
public String getStatus() {
    return dao.pullStatus();
}
```

Сей метод задает значение поля модели которая должна хранить статус выполнения операции("выполнена" или "не выполнена"). Берется это значение из поля laststatus dao объекта.
Приложение работать должно так:

Заходим на страничку http://localhost:8084/JPAsample/

На ней кнопка выполнения команды(кусочек listalldata.jsp):

```
<form action="showCat.do">  <input type="submit" value="Показать кошку по ID: "/> <input name="id" /> </form>
```

Срабатывает соответствующий метод контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping("showCat.do")
public ModelAndView showOne(long id) {
    c = dao.getCatById(id);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("listalldata");
    return mv;
}
```

Метод getCatById(id) либо найдет запись в БД либо нет. В зависимости от этого laststatus будет = "выполнена" или "не выполнена" соответственно.

Элемент:

```
<div class="status">${status}</div>
```

отображает надпись "выполнена" или "не выполнена".

На практике надпись о статусе выполнения операции меняется после второго нажатия по кнопке "Показать кошку по ID: ". Например я хочу найти кошку по id, которого нет в базе. Первоначально статус пустой. Жму "показать", статус остается пустым. Еще раз жму "показать", но уже с id, который есть в базе. Но статус становится "не выполнена". Т.е. статус обновляется с опозданием в один шаг.

Что интересно, если извратиться и распилить метод контроллера на две части вот таким образом:

```
@RequestMapping("showCat.do")
public String showOne(long id) {
    c = dao.getCatById(id);
    return "redirect:showCatPart2.do";
}

@RequestMapping("showCatPart2.do")
public ModelAndView showOneP2() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("listalldata");        
    return mv;
}
```

Информация о статусе выполнения становится актуальной. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Update.

Попытался добавить статус в ModelAndView вручную. Следующим образом:

Вариант 1:

```
@RequestMapping("showCat.do")
public ModelAndView showOne(long id) {
    c = dao.getCatById(id);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("listalldata");
    mv.addObject("cats", Collections.singletonList(c));
    mv.addObject("status");
    return mv;
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
@RequestMapping("showCat.do")
public ModelAndView showOne(@ModelAttribute("status") String status, long id) {
    c = dao.getCatById(id);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("listalldata");
    mv.addObject("cats", Collections.singletonList(c));
    mv.addObject("status", status);
    return mv;
}
```

Результат тот же.

Описание механизма работы @ModelAttribute метода нашлось в [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335432/modelattribute-in-a-method) на англоязычном "стаке" и в [этом блоге](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/11/using-spring-mvcs-modelattribute.html#.Vxdq-_mLTcf). Получается метод контроллера с аннотацией @ModelAttribute вызывается каждый раз **перед** вызовом @RequestMapping метода. Значит контроллер сперва обращается к dao объекту и читает из поля статус, а затем вызывает метод showOne(id) происходит поиск в базе и изменения статуса выполнения операции. Но в модель попадает не измененный статус, а тот, который считался до выполнения метода showOne(id). Это объясняет и запоздание обновления статуса в один шаг, и то, почему дробление метода на две части showOne(id) решает проблему.

Но тогда возникает другой вопрос: Является ли такое решение "культурным"? Возможно существует более элегантный способ.

Comment: В приведенном коде нет добавления найденного статуса в ModelAndView.